# JSP select code outputs full html source code instead of actual values

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp

I am trying to create an application that retrieves a list of all values and then populate them into an HTML select statement.

My DAO is as follows

```
 private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf) {
        this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<ExternalApp> getExternalApps() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<ExternalApp> externalAppList = session.createQuery("from ExternalApp where is_active=1").list();
        return externalAppList;
    }
```

My controller retrieves the list like this:

```
List<ExternalApp> externalAppList=this.externalAppService.getExternalApps();
model.addAttribute("externalAppList",externalAppList);
if(null!=externalAppList)
httpServletRequest.getSession().setAttribute("externalAppList", externalAppList);
```

I am trying to put this in an HTML select using the following JSP code

```
    <div class="col">
<label for="interfacesArray[0].external_interface_id" class="col-form-label required"><spring:message code="label_interface_details_interface_with" text="Interface With" /> </label>
<form:select path="interfacesArray[0].external_interface_id" class="form-control" id ="interfacesArray[0].external_interface_id" required="required" name="vabei">
<form:options itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" items="${externalAppList}"  />
</form:select>
<form:errors path="interfacesArray[0].external_interface_id" class="error help-block" />
</div>
```

where **external_interface_id** is the name of the field of the class interfaceArray

If I print the contents of externalAppList manually, I got the correct values. But the above code gives output as follows:

```
<select id="interfacesArray[0].external_interface_id"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="author" content="XXXXXXXXXXX">
    <meta name="description" content="Something">
    <meta name="referrer" content="same-origin" />
    <title></title>
    <!-- stylesheets -->


            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ggg/static/css/bootstrap.css">
```

Instead of the desired output like:

```
<select id="interfacesArray[0].external_interface_id">
<option id=1>First</option>
<option id=2>Second</option>
</select>
```

How do I fix this? Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

This is the error that is thrown

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException:
>   Invalid property 'interfacesArray[0].external_interface_id' of bean
>   class [com.ggg.model.InterfaceForm]: Bean property
>   'interfacesArray[0].external_interface_id' is not readable or has an
>   invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the
>   parameter type of the setter?

InterfaceForm simply declares an array of Interfaces class. The Interfaces class where External App is defined as

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="EXTERNAL_APP",referencedColumnName="id")
    private ExternalApp external_interface_id;
```

I am not clear about wiring (XML) and I'm guessing that might be the reason but I'm not really sure about it.

Comment: do you see any errors in logs ? Since the select is not rendered I expect there are some useful information explaining the reason for not rendering it

Comment: Could you please share the full content of output(full html source code between <select> and </select>)?

Comment: You need to add the relevant code which would be the full controller and details of how you are calling i.e. standard request or an Ajax request.

Comment: @dj_frunza I've edited the post with the error message

Comment: @AlanHay I've edited the post with more information.

Answer (score 0):

I figured the solution for this. I did not generate a getter and setter for the external_interface_id. Generating them solves the problem.